# Dependent Probability Question with Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's my question:

> Tom and Harry are dealt five cards each from the same 52-card deck.
>   Calculate the probability that Tom gets a flush (five cards of the same
>   suit) and Harry gets four of a kind. Are these two events independent?

This question is giving me some trouble - it appears to me that the events are not independent because the particular set of cards held by either player affects the probability of success of the other player. How do I attack and effectively solve this problem?

Comment: If Harry has four of a kind, it is one less card for Tom to get a flush!

Comment: I think that it depends on how the cards are dealt. And also on the Harry's fifth cards suit :)

Comment: Newb: what is the definition of independent? What is P(Tom gets flush | Harry got four of a kind)? Is that equal to P(tom gets flush)?

Answer (score 1):

Treat this situation as having to arrange 10 out of 52 cards from the given deck.
What you want is the outcome of having the first five cards of the same suit and four out of the next five also belonging to a common suit.

For the first 5 cards to be of the same suit, there are 4.5!.C(5,13) ways.
Four of the next five cards can belong to the suit same as that of Harry's cards or to a different suit.

1)For 4 of the next 5 cards to be of a the same suit as Harry's cards there are 4!.C(4,8) ways.

2)For 4 of the next 5 cards to be of a suit other than Harry's, there are 3.4!.C(4,13) ways.

The remaing card can be anything from the remaing 39 cards (assuming you want Harry to have exactly 4 cards of the same suit)

So, out of the P(10,52) ways of dealing the cards, there are 
4.5!.C(5,13)[4!.C(4,8) + 3.4!.C(4,13)]39 ways that satisfy your condition.

The probability of this happening is

4.5!.C(5,13)[4!.C(4,8) + 3.4!.C(4,13)]39/P(10,52).